# SCSS. Как использовать @extend '.class', но чтобы '.class' не появился в итоговом файле

Tags: css, gulp, sass, bower

Юзаю scss и подключаю бутсрап через @import, но что бы не захламлять html бутсраповскими классами и придерживаться бэм использую @extend , например

```
.header {
   @extend .container;
...
```

Но все классы бутсрап попадают в итоговый скомпилированный файл main.css. Вообщем вопрос в том, можно ли экстендить бутстраповские классы, но так что бы сами эти классы не попали в итоговый файл

У меня автоматически подключаются bower зависимости через wiredep

`// bower:scss`

```
@import "../../libs/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прошло чуть меньше года, дощел до нужного решения.

Вытащил нужный код из библиотеки, и добавил его в отдельный файл с миксинами, заменив создание классов `.class` на создание шаблонов `%class`. Здесь только сетка, т.к. остальное в бутсрапе не использую. Теперь код в итоговом css файле на 1.5K строчек чище

```
    %container {
        @include make-container();

        @include make-container-max-widths();
    }

    %container-fluid {
        @include make-container();
    }

    %row {
        @include make-row();
    }


    @mixin make-grid-columns($columns: $grid-columns, $gutter: $grid-gutter-width, $breakpoints: $grid-breakpoints) {
        // Common properties for all breakpoints
        %grid-column {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            padding-right: $gutter / 2;
            padding-left: $gutter / 2;
        }

        @each $breakpoint in map-keys($breakpoints) {
            $infix: breakpoint-infix($breakpoint, $breakpoints);

            // Allow columns to stretch full width below their breakpoints
            @for $i from 1 through $columns {
                %col#{$infix}-#{$i} {
                    @extend %grid-column;
                }
            }
            %col#{$infix},
            %col#{$infix}-auto {
                @extend %grid-column;
            }

            @include media-breakpoint-up($breakpoint, $breakpoints) {
                // Provide basic `.col-{bp}` classes for equal-width flexbox columns
                %col#{$infix} {
                    flex-basis: 0;
                    flex-grow: 1;
                    max-width: 100%;
                }
                %col#{$infix}-auto {
                    flex: 0 0 auto;
                    width: auto;
                    max-width: 100%; // Reset earlier grid tiers
                }

                @for $i from 1 through $columns {
                    %col#{$infix}-#{$i} {
                        @include make-col($i, $columns);
                    }
                }

                %order#{$infix}-first { order: -1; }

                %order#{$infix}-last { order: $columns + 1; }

                @for $i from 0 through $columns {
                    %order#{$infix}-#{$i} { order: $i; }
                }

                // `$columns - 1` because offsetting by the width of an entire row isn't possible
                @for $i from 0 through ($columns - 1) {
                    @if not ($infix == "" and $i == 0) { // Avoid emitting useless .offset-0
                        %offset#{$infix}-#{$i} {
                            @include make-col-offset($i, $columns);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @include make-grid-columns();

    @each $breakpoint in map-keys($grid-breakpoints) {
        @include media-breakpoint-up($breakpoint) {
            $infix: breakpoint-infix($breakpoint, $grid-breakpoints);

            @each $value in $displays {
                %d#{$infix}-#{$value} { display: $value !important; }
            }
        }
    }
```

P.S. Только `idea` ругается, что таких шаблонов не существует, ведь они создаются динамически. Не особая проблема, но решил это отметить

Comment: Какая разница между `%` и `.`?

Comment: @Antonio112009 `%template_name` не попадает в итоговую сборку, мне не нужны bootstrap классы в продакшене, все они используются через `@extend`

Comment: У меня 1 вопрос, зачем все это нужно делать, если можно было исользовать просто `extend`, а после прогнать через плагин `UnCSS`?

Comment: @E_K у меня не весь html в папке проекта, часть в cms, часть в расширениях для нее. `UnCSS` тут не поможет

Answer (score 2):

Используйте миксины sass для своих классов или создайте стили с помощью шаблонных селекторов и миксинов, а уже их используйте через `@extend`.

[Bootstrap sass mixins](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#sass-mixins)